# Conditionally instantiate assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating .obj versions of numbers in Unity.

```
void Update () {
    string scoreText = score.ToString ();
    string[] characters = new string[scoreText.index];

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++)
    {
        Instantiate (Resources.Load (characters[i]) as GameObject);
        gameObject.layer = 8;

    }
    }
```

I put all the objects in a folder called Resources in the Assets folder. 
I named them after their number ex 1, 2, 3, etc.
I turned the score into a string. 
For each character, load the asset.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`characters` is empty. You didn't put any data in it. And you didn't change layer of those instantiated game objects.

Try this

```
List<GameObject> destroyList = new List<GameObject>();

void UpdateScore()
{
    foreach (var go in destroyList)
    {
        Destroy(go);
    }
    destroyList.Clear();


    string scoreText = score.ToString ();

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++)
    {
        var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString());

        go.layer = 8;
        go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        go.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        destoryList.Add(go);
    }
}
```

You can also implement pooling for those objects for better performance.

Comment: I noticed with further debugging that characters was not returning any value. I will try this out an report back thank you.

Comment: is characters empty? I thought it was equal to scoreText.length. I am new to c#

Comment: I am trying to get the characters from the string scoreText

Comment: you've just created an array with length equals to scoreText length. you can enumerate characters by scoreText[index] or get characters' array by scoreText.ToCharArray(), the former has better performance.

Comment: I'm trying to say if char is 1, instantiate object 1 from resource folder. Can you sort of point me in the right direction for that? I'm kind of confused now

Comment: I have a score in int, i convert it to a string so that I can look at what the char is, and if the char is 1, i instantiate object 1. I thought my code would do this but I'm confused

Comment: I think the code in my answer do exactly what you've described. "3200"[0] returns '3'. Call ToString() and pass it to Resources.Load will load resource with name "3".

Comment: Wow it is instantiating my numbers. They are very huge though and they don't erase themselves they just keep coming. I tried to make them smaller like this but it didn't work. ((GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString()))).transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.002F, 0.002F, 0.002F);

Comment: Well, lots of reasons may cause this problem. Maybe something wrong with the camera. I think you should first learn the basis about Unity and C#, which won't take great effort but helps a lot.

Comment: Nah I learn by doing my projects. This is the last thing to do before this project is done too. I just have to figure out how to shrink the instantiated models

Comment: I figured out how to scale them. I will play with it more and figure out as much as I can, and then if I get stuck I will post another question. Thank you for helping me instantiate those objects!

Comment: @manbearpig1 you can try `GameObject go =  Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString())) as GameObject` and play with go like `go.layer = 8` , `go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f)` so on..

Comment: Well, I updated my answer again, it puts all the numbers at the origin of the world, you can try adjusting localPosition to the right position in the scene.

Comment: Also `Update` method is very heavy, you should put the code to somewhere to be executed only when the score has been changed. And destroy the old ones.

Comment: Yes I have noticed this. That update is beautiful btw. Inside of update it copies the score every frame and doesn't delete the old one. In its own void LoopFunction() it does not instantiate at all. What is up with that? Thanks for being my mentor today by the way

Comment: I put it in the function that changes the score like you said it works beautifully. I just don't know how to delete old scores

Comment: At the end of the for loop, add `go` to a list. Before the for loop, walk through the list and destroy every element and call list.Clear(); at last.

Comment: Ok I built this list I'm just looking up how to destroy it List<string> list = new List<string>();
   list.Add("1");
   list.Add("2");
   list.Add("3");
   list.Add("4");
   list.Add("5");
   list.Add("6");
   list.Add("7");
   list.Add("8");
   list.Add("9");
   list.Clear();

Comment: destroyList.Add(go) gives me an error it says it does not exist. Is this because we destroyed it already?

Comment: I wonder how I can separate the first number from the second so that they don't overlap. I will continue looking this up